# Pathing methods and return types

Tags: c#, methods, return-type

I know that methods are used to group codes, but how do i use the previous function of one method with another. In the section of Dealings() i want to use cards[i] in the "ShuffleCardSystem()" methods to deal out every odd position of the array. I know I have to use proper return types, and declaration, but every i tried to do it, it always ended in error.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ShuffleCardSystem();
        Dealings();

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
    static void ShuffleCardSystem()
    {
        List<string> ranks = new List<string>
         { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K" };
        int rankCounter = 0;
        List<string> suits = new List<string> { "♠", "♣", "♦", "♥" };
        int suitsCounter = 0;
        int shuffle; string temp;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int[] value = new int[52];
        string numbers = string.Empty;
        string s = string.Empty;
        string[] cards = new string[52];
        for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
        {
            cards[i] = ranks[rankCounter] + suits[suitsCounter];
            rankCounter++;
            if (rankCounter == 13)
            {
                rankCounter = 0;
                suitsCounter += 1;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 51; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            shuffle = rnd.Next(0, i);
            temp = cards[shuffle];
            cards[shuffle] = cards[i];
            cards[i] = temp;
            Console.Write(cards[i] + " ");   
        }
    }
    static void Dealing()
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using string[] as your return type for now:

```
  class Program 
  { 
       static void Main(string[] args) 
       { 
            var cards = ShuffleCardSystem(); 
            Dealings(cards);

            Console.ReadLine();

       }
       static string[] ShuffleCardSystem()
       {
           //existing code
           return cards;
       }
       static void Dealing(string[] cards)
       {
           ...
       }
  }
```

Comment: static string[] ShuffleCardSystem() there is an error in shuffle cards system it says not all path return a value @James

Comment: Make sure `return cards;` is your last line of that method

Comment: Oh wow, I am an idiot, i accidentally put in a for loop. Thanks for the help. I really appreciate it  @James